# FT Map not working in Blogger

Tags: javascript, google-maps, blogger, google-fusion-tables

I posted a FT Map in my blog. To make that I used the code from:

http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/embed_google_site.html

But unfortunelly, the GMaps' map-canvas disapeared and only the FT layers are shown. Here is the link:

http://geografiaesegurancapublica.blogspot.com.br/

Is it possible to fix this problem somehow? It would be amazing to have FT maps in Blogger!

By the way, I don't want to use an Iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walked through some of this with Daniel tonight... Using a method similar to this [solution in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948864/fusiontableslayer-hides-the-underlying-map-on-a-wordpress-page#answer-8955577) seemed to have worked.

> Specifically, the background-color setting causes the overlaid Fusion
>   Tables layers to be drawn with an opaque background, which then hides
>   the underlying map. You need to define a new class in your style sheet
>   (let's call it "map") that draws images with a transparent background...

So adding a map img class...

```
<style>
.map img {background-color: transparent;}
#map-canvas { width:400px; height:450px; }
</style>
```

...And then wrapping the maps script and map_canvas div in that class seemed to have done the trick. Any advice on another method is appreciated...

Chris K.

Comment: Good job!!! Thanks a lot, man! We are going to post a walkthrough about this in the web as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this forum answer focused on javascript within a specific post can help: 
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=853681#post7916209

-Rebecca

Comment: I tryed to use an HTML Encoder that I found here http://www.wmtips.com/tools/html-encoder/ but it didn't work (at least in the way I used it!).